# Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:5:0: unexpected end of input?

Tags: r, parsing

I have the following code, but I keep having the same error message
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): :5:0: unexpected end of input
I'm a beginner, does anyone know why?
**`plot_tile <- function(country_name_idx, country_names_list, y_lim_ranks=NA) { year_breaks <- c(2014, 2016, 2018, 2020, 2022) year_strfmt <- function(x) {return(paste("’", str_sub(x, 3, 4), sep=""))  }`

Comment: I do not really understand why you invoke parameters in your function while you do not call them afterwards. Additionally, I believe one `}`is missing at the end of your function

Comment: Thank you very much Basti! Problem solved, it came from the missing }. Thanks!